# Bounds of $f(x)= \frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $f$ be defined by:
>
> $f(x)= \frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}$
>
> 1. Prove that $f$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R+}$

I have no idea where to start, I can see by graphing it [here (desmos)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6xrf5kqvhw) that it is bounded by $0$ and $1$, but here we are not presented  with a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- for all $\,x \in \mathbb{R}^+\,$ you have $0 \le x - \lfloor x \rfloor \lt 1\,$, so $\,0 \le f(x) \lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$
- for $x \in (0,1)\,$ you have $\,\lfloor x \rfloor = 0\,$, so $\;f(x) = \sqrt{x} \lt 1$

Comment: I have thought about the first hint, but the second? How is it going to help?

Comment: If $0 \lt x \lt 1$ then $f(x) \lt 1$ by the second hint. If $x \ge 1$  then $f(x) \lt 1$ by the first hint. Put the two together, add the obvious lower bound, and you have a proof.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a function is bounded you need to **use inequalities**.

Note that

> $$x\in(0,1) \quad f(x)= \frac{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}{\sqrt x}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$$
>
> $$\forall x\geq 0 \quad f(x)= \frac{x}{\sqrt x}={\sqrt x}\leq1$$

$\implies$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}$ **f is bounded**.